# How to remove a line from a pipe-delimited file, based on the value in a particular field?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, files

I have a vertical bar delimited file as follows:

```
968666|JOHN|M|DOB
145465|DAVID|M|NULL
898563|SAUL|NULL|DOB
968666|JOHN|F|NULL
```

How do I delete the lines that have NULL in the 4th column?

Expected output

```
968666|JOHN|M|DOB
898563|SAUL|NULL|DOB
```

Comment: please click [edit] and add what you have tried yourself to solve this.. awk is better suited for field based processing..

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fields.html is a good starting point to learn about field processing with awk

Comment: Note: The `|` character is named “vertical bar”, it is used to indicate a pipe in a shell script, but has many other uses, e.g. as a delimiter (see question), at an “or”, …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed example:

```
sed '/\|.*\|.*\|NULL/d' <file>
```

sed example when NULL is always at end of line:

```
sed '/NULL$/d' <file>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F"|" '{if ($4!~/NULL/) {print $0} }'  file
```